# how to make a DISTINCT of STRING_AGG

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am trying to do a DISTINCT of the offerDetails column of the STRING_AGG function

```
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        STRING_AGG(CAST(co.OfferId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS OfferDetails, 
        STRING_AGG(CAST(ct.ConferenceId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS CustomTransferDetails
    FROM ConferenceTransfer ct
    INNER JOIN ConferenceOffer co ON ct.ConferenceId = co.ConferenceId
    WHERE
        ct.ConferenceTransferTypeId = 1 AND
        ct.DateStarted IS NOT NULL AND
        ct.CallerUserId = @agentId AND
        ct.DateInitiated BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
) CallTransfered
```

Comment: **Fix the schema!** If you have delimited data in a single column, you should regard your schema as **BROKEN**. It is a _flawed design_ that cries out for an additional table. Correct his broken design, and suddenly this query (and likely others) will be _much_ simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any native way of making string_agg distinct, but you can ignore all but the first instance of each value by using a subquery and row_number to identify the first instance, i.e.

```
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        STRING_AGG(CAST(CASE WHEN c.RowNumber = 1 THEN c.OfferId END AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS OfferDetails, 
        STRING_AGG(CAST(c.ConferenceId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS CustomTransferDetails
    FROM (  SELECT  co.OfferId,
                    ct.ConferenceId,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY co.OfferId ORDER BY ct.ConferenceId)
            FROM    ConferenceTransfer ct
                    INNER JOIN ConferenceOffer co 
                        ON ct.ConferenceId = co.ConferenceId
            WHERE
                ct.ConferenceTransferTypeId = 1 AND
                ct.DateStarted IS NOT NULL AND
                ct.CallerUserId = @agentId AND
                ct.DateInitiated BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
            ) AS c
) CallTransfered
```

The key part being `CASE WHEN c.RowNumber = 1 THEN c.OfferId END`, so for anything other than the first instance, you are passing NULL, so the end result will only contain each `OfferId` once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `OfferId`, then group again

```sql
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        STRING_AGG(CAST(c.OfferId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS OfferDetails, 
        STRING_AGG(c.CustomTransferDetails, ';') AS CustomTransferDetails
    FROM (
        SELECT
            co.OfferId,
            STRING_AGG(CAST(ct.ConferenceId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS CustomTransferDetails
        FROM ConferenceTransfer ct
        INNER JOIN ConferenceOffer co ON ct.ConferenceId = co.ConferenceId
        WHERE
            ct.ConferenceTransferTypeId = 1 AND
            ct.DateStarted IS NOT NULL AND
            ct.CallerUserId = @agentId AND
            ct.DateInitiated BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
        GROUP BY
            co.OfferId
    ) c
) CallTransfered
```

This obviously only works for one `DISTINCT`. If you need both to be distinct, you can re-split the values, distinct them and re-aggregate

```sql
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
        (
            SELECT
                STRING_AGG(s.value, ';')
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT s.value
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(OfferDetails, ';') s
            ) s
        ) AS OfferDetails, 
        (
            SELECT
                STRING_AGG(s.value, ';')
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT s.value
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(ConferenceId, ';') s
            ) s
        ) AS CustomTransferDetails
    FROM (
        SELECT
            STRING_AGG(CAST(co.OfferId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS OfferDetails, 
            STRING_AGG(CAST(ct.ConferenceId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';') AS CustomTransferDetails
        FROM ConferenceTransfer ct
        INNER JOIN ConferenceOffer co ON ct.ConferenceId = co.ConferenceId
        WHERE
            ct.ConferenceTransferTypeId = 1 AND
            ct.DateStarted IS NOT NULL AND
            ct.CallerUserId = @agentId AND
            ct.DateInitiated BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
        GROUP BY
            co.OfferId
    ) c
) CallTransfered
```